# Subset and subspace synonymous sometimes?

Tags: functional-analysis

Subset and subspace synonymous sometimes?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set

> A is dense in X if and only if the only closed subset of X containing A is X itself.

However, also

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2019863/248602

Particularly,

> is contained in some **closed proper subspace** of X, and therefore cannot be dense.

---

Or is it because a subspace is always a subset. However, that a subset may not necessarily be a subspace?

Comment: There is a big difference between subset and subspace. Being a subset of $X$ simply means that you only contain points (or functions, or objects, etc) that lie inside $X$, and nothing more. Being a subspace usually carries additional meaning; for instance, a vector subspace requires you to be a subset, plus contain the zero element of X, be closed under addition, etc.

Comment: Any subset can be equipped with the [subspace topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology), which makes it a subspace, but for some purposes (such as defining "dense subset") all we need is a subset.

Comment: @Bungo So subspace is a stronger form of subset?

Comment: Subspace is a topological space, subset is a set. Those are two different things

Comment: A subspace is a subset along with a particular topology on that subset.